# How to check/update columns in a database contains about million rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, pdo

I have MYSQL Database that contains about one Million (1,000,000) rows , I want to check all the rows and update some according to a condition , So for example I run a SQL statement like this:

```
select messageid from messages where messageid !=""
```

Then I fetch all the IDs and store them in a variable:

```
$existMessages;
```

Then I generate a 4 characters string 0-9a-z :

```
function generateRandomString($length = 4) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($y='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($y)) )),1,$length);
}
```

Then I update the existing IDs with the generated strings , After checking that the generated IDs are unique.

This process becomes slower and takes the whole CPU as the rows are increasing.

Is there is a better way to do that ? Like using SQL statements directly in MYSQL? Or what to do ?

Comment: you should use [MySQL Store Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)

Comment: Perhaps this is a one time thing to make them all have it and wherever these are being inserted should also have the addition of the unique IDs? Then you wouldn't have to do this?

Comment: @James , Yes in general this should be the same , But this is a special case and I need to update this column from time to time with unique random value

Comment: "from time to time" but if this was in the INSERT code, you'd not need to do this ever again? The insert would have already done it

Comment: Only a million, I had a table with 120 million, then we moved it to MongoDB, mostly because it was consuming over 80GB of HD and 30GB or ram, not that MongoDB does a better job at that.  A million is small potatoes, I have 2 tables right now with just over a million :-)

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this query `select messageid from messages where messageid !=""` you select the id, by the id when you know what the id is?  Maybe it's just an example but its a bad one, as there are ways to optimize selects, but we would need the real select.  For example if you have a unique field and you want to insert data, it's faster to catch the duplicate key errors then to do a select and insert, because you don't have to run 1 of the queries.

Comment: @James , That's because isn't the column auto-increment id , there are id and messageid , id is auto-increment where messageid is a unique string , Like when you want to create an activation link so you create random key

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix , Some rows already contain a random string , Now there are new created rows , So I select all the ids to make sure that the ids are not duplicated

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, or you me. I'll be clear as possible. You insert a row, in that row is the field `messageid`. Later you come along and on that same row in `messageid` you update with data. If this is for any/all rows where `messageid` is empty, then it should be being set on the first insert. And/or whenever any script empties this field it should call the script you generate the random code from and update it then with that. ie whenever ANY script actions this table and that field, if it'll be empty then set the thing then rather than setting it to empty and later fixing that :)

Comment: What database driver, are you using, mysqli or PDO, have you tried using un-buffered queries for the select?  Typically it's going to be a trade off between time and memory. `for your comment` what i am saying is I don't understand why you have empty id's instead of just deleting and inserting, updates are slower then either of those 2.

Comment: Looks like you have a design problem since updating IDs is really infrequent. This could be a one time operation to fix the flaw but should  not be needed as a maintenance task. Perhaps a TRIGGER that acts upon INSERT could be better to fix incorrect IDs.

Comment: It seems I'm not making it clear , The `messageid` column is not the row id , I don't want to insert numbers there , I'm not ordering the table with that column , There is column called `id` for that purpose

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix , I'm using PDO

Comment: Ok but you still haven't given me enough info, what is the query for this `Then I update the existing IDs with the generated strings`. Is  ID unique, etc...  IF you have  a million rows there is a good chance your random will generate the same string more then one time, expecially with `$length = 4`  or ( 62 * 62 * 62 *62 = 14,776,336)

Comment: so you see you have basically a 1 in 14 chance, when you have 1million rows in there.  This gets worse every time you add a row.

Answer (score 0):

You should first put a `unique or primary` constraint on the column you want to be unique.

After that you can execute the update command

`UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLMUN_NAME=generateRandomString() WHERE messageid !="";`

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQL directly, and create a simple hash based upon some data in the row, for instance:

`UPDATE table_name SET messageid = MD5(messageid) WHERE messageid !="";`

You might want to do that in batches, so add a LIMIT to the statement, ie. LIMIT 0,1000 to do bunch at a time.

Comment: "This process becomes slower and takes the whole CPU as the rows are increasing." qeuries with LIMIT will also get slower when larger offset numbers are been used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below update clause. This will pick 4 random letters and numbers for both lower and upper case and 0-9.

```
update table_name cross join (select 
@chars:='1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') tab
set messageid = concat(substring(@chars, floor(rand()*61) + 1, 1),
               substring(@chars, floor(rand()*61) + 1, 1),
               substring(@chars, floor(rand()*61) + 1, 1),
              substring(@chars, floor(rand()*61) + 1, 1)
          )
where messageid !="";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll eliminate the need for the 'check', and make it faster.

There are not many more than a million such 4-character strings.  So, there will be an annoying number of duplicates if you 'randomly' generate them.

Instead, I recommend

1. Generate all of them (or a million of them)
2. Shuffle them
3. Apply them to your table.

   - `CONV(x, 10, 36)` will generate a base-36 (0-9A-Z) value from x.  But, The following may be better...
   - Build a table with 36 rows of 0..9,a..z.
   - `CROSS JOIN` it to itself 4 times to generate all 36^4 combos.
   - `ORDER BY RAND()` will shuffle them without leading to dups.
   - A multi-table `UPDATE` will let you copy the 4-char string from one table to another.